# Forward traffic from mac-os client to windows laptop

Tags: networking, mac, vpn, routing

Scenario
PC-1 = Mac Client
PC-2 = Windows Client (with cisco remote access vpn)

Hello Everyone,
I'd like to let my mac client forward packet through some destination (that I specified as static route) via windows laptop. This laptop is connected to a full tunnel cisco vpn. Without the vpn everything works fine with the "IP Enable Route" seated from regedit, but when I connect the vpn the destination subnet are not more accessible from the mac client.

Is possible to archive that ?

Thank you

Comment: Not without changing the VPN configuration

Comment: I also have the possibility to connect to a VPN with a split tunnel. but in this case, I would need to route the traffic from my Mac client to Windows client, and then this traffic would need to go through the VPN anyway.